# Java Interfaces and Implementation

Tags: java, web-services, jsf, el

I am consuming a webservice using my java web application.This returns a number of data among which there is a attribute named `Consumer`. This is represented as an object when the WSDL is converted to Java code. There is only one string variable `id` inside this class. There is another class `Person` which extends `Consumer`. This has a number fields like `firstName` , `lastName` etc. In the JSF code , there is a reference to `consumer.firstName` and the value pertaining to `firstName` is being printed properly when person object is returned as part of response xml. This confuses me a bit because consumer object does not contain `firstName` and still the value is getting printed properly when `consumer.firstName` is used. Please can you help me in understanding this.

JSF Code

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.consumer.firstName}" />
```

Backing Bean

```
public Consumer getConsumer() {
  return consumer;
}
```

Consumer Class

```
public class Consumer implements java.io.Serializable {

  private java.lang.String id;

  public java.lang.String getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(java.lang.String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

}
```

Person Class

```
public class Person extends Consumer {
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private String dateOfBirth;

     // Getters and Setters
}
```

Comment: A little code is worth a thousand words...

Comment: Thanks Crowder - added some code.

Comment: That's more the job of EL than JSF itself. Put your mouse above the `[el]` tag which I just put below your question until a black info box shows up and then click therein the *info* link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSF uses reflection to call the methods on your objects. It doesn't know what the type of `myBean.consumer` is. All it knows is that you asked the `firstName` of this object. So, what it does is

1. Find an attribute, in any scope, named myBean
2. if not null, find if there is a public no-arg method named "getConsumer" in the class (or any superclass or interface) of this object
3. Call this method, and get the result: another object
4. if this other object is not null, find if there is a public no-arg method named "getFirstName" in the class (or any superclass or interface) of this other object
5. Call this method

So, even if the method `getConsumer()` declares that it returns a `Consumer`, if, at runtime, the actual object returned by `getConsumer()` is a `Person`, JSF will search for a `getFirstName()` method in `Person`, it will find it, and will happily call it and outut its result.

Comment: Thanks - helps my understanding. So even if some other object that is not related to consumer is returned - it will happily execute if it finds the method on this object.

Comment: Yes, except it's impossible for a method returning a Consumer to return something "not related to Consumer". It returns either null, or an instance of Consumer. Person being a subclass of Consumer, a Person instance **is** a Consumer.

Comment: Cool - Thanks. So if the method returns Object , JSF can accept and execute the method :)

Comment: Yes indeed. You got it. If the object returned is not null, and doesn't have any getFirstName() method, an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

When at JSF you refer to `consumer.firstName`, it's not the type `Consumer` you are accesing, but an *attribute* of your page/request/session. 
This attribute can be set as of a concrete type (`Person`) extending `Consumer`, and thus it presents a `firstName` value.

Comment: Thanks - I am returning Consumer object which does not contain firstName or lastName. I thought when Person is returned , java will invoke overridden methods of Person object polymorphically. But Consumer reference does not contain methods for getting firstName - hence a bit confused still.

Answer (score 2):

In your JSF page, right before you print the firstName of what you think it's a Consumer instance, also print the value of "consumer.class.simpleName". Most likely this will print "Person" as your object is an instance of "Person" (and it's polymorphically treated as a Consumer type, because in this case a Person instance is also of type Consumer).

Comment: Hi, In the backing bean I need to cast it using Person object to get the same information. So , is JSF automatically adding the cast?

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure JSF doesn't do the cast (it wouldn't know to what to cast it without you telling him specifically). I think it just does some introspection on your instance, where it looks for a getter method corresponding to the attribute name you've given, and returns the return value of invoking that method (via reflection). Eg: for person.firstName, it looks for a method named getFirstName(), if it finds it on the object it invokes it, and then it shows the value of the return object.